# Running sonar Qube scanner project are marked as invalid

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm running Sonarqube Scanner for MSBuild from Jenkins.

The projects are in VS2013 but I'm building it with MSBuild 14.

The build is successful but only a few files are being scanned (10)

On the Sonarqube scanner log if war able to find a huge list of project flagged as "Invalid projects", I'm not sure why is that happening.

**Another info**: is that build itself takes 14min when I added sonar scanner 1+ hour

```
Product projects
---------------------------------------
e:\jenkins\workspace\XXXX.YY.csproj

Test projects
---------------------------------------


Invalid projects
---------------------------------------
e:\jenkins\workspace\WWWW.RR.csproj
e:\jenkins\workspace\TTTT.JJ.csproj
{none}


Skipped projects
---------------------------------------
{none}


Excluded projects
---------------------------------------
{none}
```

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild considers projects invalid if they don't contain a project guid property `<ProjectGuid>{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}</ProjectGuid>` (or if it is equal to Guid.Empty) and are not included in a solution. To resolve this you should ensure you have unique `ProjectGuid` in each project.

The analysis adds some overhead, usually it is increasing the compilation time quite significantly, especially if you enable many rules. The default quality profile should not increase the compilation more than 2-3 times, though.

What version of the Scanner for MSBuild, SonarC# and SonarQube are you using? Since your projects are for VS2013, I suspect that you might be using the MSBiuld 12 fallback, which is both slower and imprecise (because during the analysis each file is included in a temp project and compiled separately) than the MSBuild 14 mode. Good way to ensure you are using MSBuild 14 mode is to use Scanner for MSBuild 3.0+ and SonarC# 6.0+, because they no longer support MSBuild 12 mode...

Comment: Hi Valeri,first of all, thanks for your answer, yes I'm building with MSBuild 14 and the version of the SonarQube scanner is 2.6. At the moment I'm performing a test  to change ToolsVersion="14.0" it was in 12. I'll let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this out by invoking the exectuable directly using powershell

First Step Initialize

```
cd "<Project root folder>"
& "E:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:"<project key>" /n:"<project name>" /v:"<version>" /d:sonar.host.url=<URL> /d:sonar.login=<Token>
```

Second Step

```
MS Build
```

Third Step

```
   & "E:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.2.656\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end
```